# Abstraction for an IO device

Tags: c++, linux, io

I have a C++ class which acts as an abstraction for an IO device which is controlled through file descriptors. As I am very new to C++, I would be glad if you can give me devastating feedback on things I've done wrong.

This especially covers:

- Code style
- Design patterns
- Error handling
- Things which are open for failures
- C++ approaches which can be used over C approaches (file IO)

**gpio.h**

```
#ifndef SRC_GPIO_H_
#define SRC_GPIO_H_

#define GPIO_IN     0
#define GPIO_OUT    1

#define GPIO_LOW    0
#define GPIO_HIGH   1

class GPIO {
    public:
        explicit GPIO(int id);
        ~GPIO();

        int  Value();
        void Value(int value);
        int  Direction();
        void Direction(int value);

    private:
        int _id;
        int _value_fd;
        int _direction_fd;

        bool Exists();
        void Export();
        void Unexport();
        void OpenValueFd();
        void OpenDirectionFd();
        void CloseValueFd();
        void CloseDirectionFd();
        void SeekToTopOfValueFd();
        void SeekToTopOfDirectionFd();
};

#endif
```

**gpio.cc**

```
#include "../src/gpio.h"

#define GPIO_PATH_EXPORT        "/sys/class/gpio/export"
#define GPIO_PATH_UNEXPORT      "/sys/class/gpio/unexport"
#define GPIO_PATH_DIRECTORY     "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d"
#define GPIO_PATH_DIRECTION     "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/direction"
#define GPIO_PATH_VALUE         "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value"

GPIO::GPIO(int id) {
    Export();

    OpenValueFd();
    OpenDirectionFd();
}

GPIO::~GPIO() {
    CloseValueFd();
    CloseDirectionFd();

    Unexport();
}

bool
GPIO::Exists() {
    char * path;

    if (asprintf(&path, GPIO_PATH_DIRECTORY, id) < 0)
        throw "Error generationg GPIO directory path.";

    int result = access(path, F_OK);

    free(path);

    return static_cast<bool> result++;
}

void
GPIO::Export() {
    char * id;

    if (Exists()) return;

    if (asprintf(&id, "%d", _id) < 0)
        throw "Error converting id to char.";

    int fd = open(GPIO_PATH_EXPORT, O_WRONLY);

    if (fd < 0)
        throw "Error opening GPIO export.";

    if (write(fd, id, strlen(id)) < 0)
        throw "Error writing to GPIO export.";

    if (close(fd) < 0)
        throw "Error closing GPIO export.";

    free(id);
}

void
GPIO::Unexport() {
    char * id;

    if (!Exists()) return;

    if (asprintf(&id, "%d", _id) < 0)
        throw "Error converting id to char.";

    int fd = open(GPIO_PATH_UNEXPORT, O_WRONLY);

    if (fd < 0)
        throw "Error opening GPIO unexport.";

    if (write(fd, id, strlen(id)) < 0)
        throw "Error writing to GPIO unexport.";

    if (close(fd) < 0)
        throw "Error closing GPIO unexport.";

    free(id);
}

int
GPIO::Value() {
    char data[2];

    SeekValueFdToTop();

    data[1] = 0;

    if (read(_value_fd, data, 1) < 0)
        throw "Error reading from GPIO value.";

    if (strncmp(data, "0", 1) == 0)
        return GPIO_LOW;
    if (strncmp(data, "1", 1) == 0)
        return GPIO_HIGH;

    throw "Invalid GPIO value.";
}

void
GPIO::Value(int value) {
    SeekValueFdToTop();

    switch (value) {
        case GPIO_LOW:
            if (write(_value_fd, "0\n", 2) < 0)
                throw "Error writing to GPIO value.";
            break;
        case GPIO_HIGH:
            if (write(_value_fd, "1\n", 2) < 0)
                throw "Error writing to GPIO value.";
            break;
        default:
            throw "Error cannot set invalid GPIO value.";
    }
}

int
GPIO::Direction() {
    char data[4];

    SeekValueFdToTop();

    data[3] = 0;

    if (read(_direction_fd, data, 1) < 0)
        throw "Error reading from GPIO direction.";

    if (strncmp(data, "in", 2) == 0)
        return GPIO_IN;
    if (strncmp(data, "out", 3) == 0)
        return GPIO_OUT;

    throw "Invalid GPIO direction.";
}

void
GPIO::Direction(int value) {
    SeekValueFdToTop();

    switch (value) {
        case GPIO_IN:
            if (write(_value_fd, "in\n", 3) < 0)
                throw "Error writing to GPIO direction.";
            break;
        case GPIO_OUT:
            if (write(_value_fd, "out\n", 4) < 0)
                throw "Error writing to GPIO direction.";
            break;
        default:
            throw "Error cannot set invalid GPIO direction.";
    }
}

void
GPIO::OpenValueFd() {
    char * path;

    if (asprintf(&path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, _id) < 0)
        throw "Error generating GPIO value path.";

    if ((_value_fd = open(path, O_RDWR)) < 0)
        throw "Error opening GPIO value.";

    free(path);
}

void
GPIO::OpenDirectionFd() {
    char * path;

    if (asprintf(&path, GPIO_PATH_DIRECTION, _id) < 0)
        throw "Error generating GPIO direction path.";

    if ((_direction_fd = open(path, O_RDWR)) < 0)
        throw "Error opening GPIO direction.";

    free(path);
}

void
GPIO::CloseValueFd() {
    if (close(_value_fd) < 0)
        throw "Error closing GPIO value.";
}

void
GPIO::CloseDirectionFd() {
    if (close(_direction_fd) < 0)
        throw "Error closing GPIO direction.";
}

void
GPIO::SeekToTopOfValueFd() {
    if (lseek(_value_fd, SEEK_SET, 0) < 0)
        throw "Error seeking to top of GPIO value.";
}

void
GPIO::SeekToTopOfDirectionFd() {
    if (lseek(_direction_fd, SEEK_SET, 0) < 0)
        throw "Error seeking to top of GPIO direction.";
}
```

Source can be found [here](https://github.com/bodokaiser/node-native-gpio/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Prefer the  C++ way

As you seem to expect, one of the key issues with your code is that it's not very C++y.

#### 1. Prefer `std::string` over C-style strings.

[`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is better in almost every way. It takes care of its own memory and grows when needed. The speed is usually comparable to C-style strings (sometimes faster, sometimes slower). The code written using `string` is often more readable. For example, compare your code:

```
if (strncmp(data, "in", 2) == 0)
```

with the `std::string` variant:

```
if (data == "in")
```

#### 2. Prefer `iostream` to `FILE*`.

The C++ library for IO is typesafe, extensible, object-oriented and should be preferred. Use an `ifstream` to read from a file and `ofstream` to write, or `fstream` for both.

#### 3. Consider throwing exceptions derived from `std::runtime_error` and `std::logic_error`

By having an exception hierarchy, you can have fine grained control over which errors to catch where. Your code will also play nice with others, who might expect your exceptions to behave like the standard ones. Want to catch everything? Catch `std::exception`. Want to catch only your own? Do so. Want to get the error message? Call `.what()`.

Remember that exceptions should always be thrown by value, and `catch`ed (caught) by reference(-to-`const`).

#### 4. Prefer `enum` or `const`s to `#define`d constants.

Instead of

```
#define GPIO_IN     0
#define GPIO_OUT    1
```

write

```
enum IODirection { GPIO_IN = 0, GPIO_OUT = 1 };
```

For your path name `#define`s, use `const std::string` instead. (And consider moving them into class scope as `static`, or into a namespace.)

You get type safety, easier debugging, normal scope rules; the works.

#### 5. Avoid leading underscores in identifiers.

The following identifiers are **reserved**:

- Any name that begins with an underscore and is in the global namespace.
- Any name that begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter.
- Any name that contains two consecutive underscores.

While your `_id` and similar variables are technically correct, don't rely on yourself or others memorizing these rules. Play it safe and move the underscore to the other side: `id_`, or drop it altogether.

### Other things

These are mostly nitpicking, but you asked for a "very critical review" :-)

#### 6. `#include` the proper headers.

I'm guessing you already are, and that maybe they were removed when posting the code for review. I'm mentioning it just in case. It's nice to include `#include`s in the review code, too.

#### 7. Let the build system take care of include paths.

Instead of: `#include "../src/gpio.h"`, prefer to just use `#include "gpio.h"` and let the preprocessor and build system take care of finding the right header for you. This makes it a lot easier to move files at a later point.

#### 8. Don't cast unless you have to.

Instead of

```
return static_cast<bool> result++;
```

write

```
return result++ != 0;
```

(And use parenthesis on your casts.)

#### 9. Use `fclose()` instead of `close()`.

The C library function is called `fclose()`. (This is a moot point, however, since you should prefer C++ IO anyway.)

#### 10. Use descriptive names and a clear interface

Your public interface functions have names that imply that they don't change the state of the class. If they don't, make the functions `const`. (Your `Exists()` function should at least be `const`. The same *may* apply to functions that are only reading.) Consider separating the state changing functionality from the non-state-changing functionality, and putting the latter into `const` functions.

Rename functions that *do* change state to reflect that.

Finally, `data` is a classic, horrible variable name. I'm sure you can do better!

Answer (score 6):

A few points to add to those from @Lstor.

Firstly I'm puzzled about the underlying GPIO devices - why use character
strings in the interface to a GPIO?

And quite fundamentally, you don't seem to have compiled your code.

- `GPIO::GPIO()`: id is not used (to set the class variable)
- `GPIO::Exists()`: uses `id` not `_id`
- `GPIO::Exists()`: return statement is missing brackets.
- `SeekValueFdToTop` des not exist (called in `Value` and `Direction` functions)

---

In `GPIO::Exists()` the `result++` gets it wrong in two ways:

- firstly it is horrible to rely on the -1/0 return from `access` to to
  be turned into 0/1 by incrementing
- secondly you use post-increment, so it doesn't happen.

You should be using

```
return result == 0; // returns `true` if file exists
```

---

You use `asprintf` everywhere.  I had to look that up and find it is a
non-standard function that allocates the necessary string.  Using it to create
paths on-demand seems unnecessary.  You could create the base path just once
in the constructor.  But I'm a C-guy and all that allocation/deallocation is
foreign to me.  I guess C++ strings will be doing that in the background if
you use strings instead...

---

You should use brackets, even when not strictly needed:

```
if (asprintf(&path, GPIO_PATH_VALUE, _id) < 0) {
    throw "Error generating GPIO value path.";
}
```

---

Your `Value` and `Direction` functions have various issues.

- Using `strncmp` in `Value` to check for "0" and "1" is not sensible. Instead, use

  ```
  if (data[0] == '0') {...}
  ```

  although `data` does not need to be an array when reading a single char.
- I think you should have separate get/set functions rather than overloading
  `Value` and `Direction` to mean either get or set.
- You use non-existent `SeekValueFdToTop` in both the `Value` and `Direction` functions.
  The appropriate functions are `SeekToTopOfValueFd` and
  `SeekToTopOfDirectionFd`.