# GPIO wrapper class

Tags: c++

I've received reviews on the last version [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28455/c-class-needs-a-very-critical-review), but as an update would make the answers not fitting anymore, I think it is wise to open a new post.

I followed most of the hints of the last review and now want to check if I done things write or made new mistakes.

If you are interested in the complete source click [here](https://github.com/bodokaiser/node-native-gpio/blob/2902666f9cd5ceb99b3edaf698a8a217572d7a92/src/gpio.cc)

**gpio.h**

```
#ifndef SRC_GPIO_H_
#define SRC_GPIO_H_

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::fstream;

enum GPIODirection {
    GPIO_IN  = 0,
    GPIO_OUT = 1
};

enum GPIOValue {
    GPIO_LOW  = 0,
    GPIO_HIGH = 1
};

class GPIO {
    public:
        explicit GPIO(int id);
        ~GPIO();

        int  Value();
        void Value(int value);
        int  Direction();
        void Direction(int value);

    private:
        int id_;

        fstream value_;
        fstream direction_;

        bool Exists();
        void Export();
        void Unexport();

        static const string PATH_EXPORT;
        static const string PATH_UNEXPORT;
        static const string PREFIX;
        static const string POSTFIX_VALUE;
        static const string POSTFIX_DIRECTION;
};

#endif
```

**gpio.cc**

```
#include "gpio.h"

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::ios;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::logic_error;
using std::runtime_error;

const string GPIO::PATH_EXPORT       = "/sys/class/gpio/export";
const string GPIO::PATH_UNEXPORT     = "/sys/class/gpio/unexport";
const string GPIO::PREFIX            = "/sys/class/gpio/gpio";
const string GPIO::POSTFIX_VALUE     = "/value";
const string GPIO::POSTFIX_DIRECTION = "/direction";

GPIO::GPIO(int id) {
    id_ = id;

    Export();

    stringstream value_path;
    stringstream direction_path;

    value_path << PREFIX;
    value_path << id;
    value_path << POSTFIX_VALUE;

    direction_path << PREFIX;
    direction_path << id;
    direction_path << POSTFIX_DIRECTION;

    value_.open(value_path.str().c_str());
    direction_.open(direction_path.str().c_str());
}

GPIO::~GPIO() {
    value_.close();
    direction_.close();

    Unexport();
}

bool
GPIO::Exists() {
    stringstream path;

    path << PREFIX;
    path << id_;

    fstream gpio;

    gpio.open(path.str().c_str());

    bool result = gpio.good();

    gpio.close();

    return result;
}

void
GPIO::Export() {
    if (Exists()) return;

    fstream gpio_export;
    stringstream string_stream;

    string_stream << id_;

    gpio_export.open(PATH_EXPORT.c_str(), ios::out);
    gpio_export << string_stream.str();
    gpio_export.close();
}

void
GPIO::Unexport() {
    if (!Exists()) return;

    fstream gpio_unexport;
    stringstream string_stream;

    string_stream << id_;

    gpio_unexport.open(PATH_UNEXPORT.c_str(), ios::out);
    gpio_unexport << string_stream.str();
    gpio_unexport.close();
}

int
GPIO::Value() {
    string value;

    value_.seekp(0);
    value_ >> value;

    if (value == "0") return GPIO_LOW;
    if (value == "1") return GPIO_HIGH;

    throw logic_error("Invalid GPIO value.");
}

void
GPIO::Value(int value) {
    value_.seekp(0);

    switch (value) {
        case GPIO_LOW:
            value_ << "0" << endl; 

            if (!value_.good())
                throw runtime_error("Error writting to value file stream.");

            break;
        case GPIO_HIGH:
            value_ << "1" << endl; 

            if (!value_.good())
                throw runtime_error("Error writting to value file stream.");

            break;
        default:
            throw logic_error("Error cannot set invalid GPIO value.");
    }
}

int
GPIO::Direction() {
    string direction;

    direction_.seekp(0);

    direction_ >> direction;

    if (direction == "in") return GPIO_IN;
    if (direction == "out") return GPIO_OUT;

    throw logic_error("Invalid GPIO direction.");
}

void
GPIO::Direction(int value) {
    direction_.seekp(0);

    switch (value) {
        case GPIO_IN:
            direction_ << "in" << endl;

            if (!direction_.good())
                throw runtime_error("Error writting to direciton file stream.");

            break;
        case GPIO_OUT:
            direction_ << "out" << endl;

            if (!direction_.good())
                throw runtime_error("Error writting to direciton file stream.");

            break;
        default:
            throw logic_error("Error cannot set invalid GPIO direction.");
    }
}
```

Things I guess could be done better:

- class methods
- implementation of Exist()
- error handling
- string formatting
- path constants
- int to string cast (std::to_string seems not to be available)

Comment: Check this out for argument about explicitly calling close: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/540/507

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some quick remarks:

- To me, `value` and `direction` don't sound like stream names. Maybe they should be called something else? It depends on the domain terminology (which I'm not familiar with).
- Don't ever pollute the global namespace by using `using` in headers. Write the full qualifiers.
- Your `stringstream` operations look like they can be factored out into a separate function.
- Note that `std::endl` forces a stream flush. If you just want the newline, use `<< '\n'` instead.
- I think it's nice to sort `#include`s alphabetically.
- In C++11, `fstream::open` takes a `std::string` argument as well.
- Consider changing the names of `Value` and `Direction` (like William Morris points out in the other review). If a function changes the state of the object, it should be named differently (probably with a verb).
- Prefer to initialize variables using initializer lists in constructors.
- Your `Value` and `Direction` functions are nearly identical.

You can refactor to something like this:

```
std::string GPIO::ReadFromBeginningOfStream(std::fstream& stream)
{
    stream.seekg(0); // NOTE: seekg, *not* seekp
    std::string tmp;
    stream >> tmp;
    return tmp;
}

int
GPIO::Value() {
    std::string const& value = ReadFromBeginningOfStream(value_);

    if (value == "0") return GPIO_LOW;
    if (value == "1") return GPIO_HIGH;

    throw logic_error("Invalid GPIO value.");
}
```

And then similar but with passing in the other stream in `Direction()`.

**NOTE:** Seek in an *input* stream by calling `seekg()`; in an *output* stream by calling `seekp()`.

- `Exists()` should be `const`, like this: `bool Exists() const;`

Comment: What do you mean with the "using" headers? Should I just always use std::string or v8::Object? I renamed the functions to SetValue, GetValue, ... I also need "<< std::endl" else the value is not written (tried this already) Also I get a compiler error on settings Exists() const

Comment: You can use `using` in implementation files (preferably inside each function), but not in headers. If you need flushing, then use `endl` like you are, I just mentioned it :-) Which error do you get if you set `Exists()` to const?

Comment: (You added the `const` to `Exists()` in both the declaration and definition, right?)

Comment: When I just put `bool Exists() const` to the header the compiler says that Exists() does not match any declaration

Comment: ah you have to place the const in the implementation between Exists() and opening bracket - did not knew this